# Curve in an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_3, \lambda_3$ be distinct real numbers. Can it be that a curve of the form
$$ t \mapsto \gamma(t) := (e^{\lambda_1 t}, e^{\lambda_2 t}, e^{\lambda_3 t})
$$
is contained for all times $t \ge 0$ in an algebraic variety of the form
$$ 
 a_1 x_1^k + a_2 x_2^k + a_3 x_3^k = 0 ?
$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  Then we would have $a_1 e^{\lambda_1 k t} + a_2 e^{\lambda_2 k t} + a_3 e^{\lambda_3 k t}$ for all $t$.  But the $e^{\lambda_i t}$ are linearly independent as functions (which follows from, say, the Vandermonde determinant, though for real $\lambda_i$ you can show this with a limit argument), so $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you be a bit more precise with your argument in the brackets?

Comment: @samsa44 Which one?  The limit approach is probably the most elegant (though it suddenly looks ugly when you try to generalize it to complex numbers).  The limit proof is a proof by induction: you isolate the fastest-growing exponential, divide the whole equation by that, take the limit $t\to\infty$, and conclude that the coefficient in front of the largest exponential is zero.

Comment: Perhaps he's wondering about the relevance of the Vandermonde determinant? (To which I'd say, identically zero includes being zero for all derivatives...).